# preg_match many word in Simple way

Tags: php

```
$text = text1 text2 text3 text4 

if (preg_match('/text1/',$text )) 
    $replacetext1= 'replacetext1'; 
else 
    $replacetext1='';

if (preg_match('/text2/',$text )) 
    $replacetext2= 'replacetext2'; 
else 
    $replacetext2='';

if (preg_match('/text3/',$text )) 
    $replacetext3= 'replacetext3'; 
else 
    $replacetext3='';

if (preg_match('/text4/',$text )) 
    $replacetext4= 'replacetext4'; 
else 
    $replacetext4='';
```

```
result = replacetext1 replacetext2 replacetext3 replacetext4
```

I want to do with input and its auto replace

```
text1 | replacetext1 
text2 | replacetext2 
text3 | replacetext3 
text4 | replacetext4

FORMAT: KEYWORD|RESONSE-1|
```

is have any simple way for word replace ??

Comment: `$text = text1 text2 text3 text4 ` is invalid PHP syntax. What do you mean with this? Can you give an example in valid syntax?

Comment: Both pattern and replacement could be arrays (mapping onto each other). More fancy would be an alternatives list, a lookup array, and a callback. It's unclear why you generate 4 output variables though.

Comment: `/\b(word1|word2|word3)\b/` - simple, or if you need distinct replacement for each match use 2 arrays, or 1 array with the keys for one argument the values for another.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix can you elaborate properly ??

Comment: What @mario said with `preg_replace`, and use `str_replace` if you don't need regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array support of [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$text = "text1 text2 text3";
$result = str_replace(["text1","text2","text3"], ["repl1", "repl2", "repl3"], $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$text = "text4 text1 text2 text3";
$replace = [
  '/\btext1\b/'         => 'replace1', //replace case sensitive
  '/\btext2\b/i'         => 'replace2', //non-sensitive
  '/\b(text3|text4)\b/i' => 'replace3', //replace both text3 and text4
];
$result = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
```

The main thing here is the `\b` or word boundary, this is anything that is not `0-9a-zA-Z_`, which prevents partial matches.  But in theory you can use any regex for any of the items in the array.  Which gives you more flexibility over other replacement methods.

Output:

```
 replace3 replace1 replace2 replace3
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f1295117a05ba75cb0ef03188655d8eefb87300)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use implode/explode method like this:

```
$text = "text1 text2 text3 text4";
// define your replacement strings
$replace = [
  'text1' => 'replace1',
  'text2' => 'replace2',
  'text3' => 'replace3',
  'text4' => 'replace4',
];
$result = $text;
foreach($replace as $i => $v){
  $result = implode($v, explode($i, $result ));
}
echo $result ;
```